# Text isn't overlapping on the background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use two different background colors for different sections of the page. Right now I haven't scaled it appropriately but I'm currently just trying to fix this issue. The issue is that the text doesn't appear over the background, but instead under it.

The expected output is that the text is above the background colors.
The actual output is that the text appears below the whole background (Not behind, but below it).

```css
.bg-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.top {
  height: 50vh;
  background: #76a3b1;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.title1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
<div class="main-page">
  <span class="title1">
            TEXT
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text doesn't appear over the background because you put the text  `span` after the background in your HTML. move the `span` "inside" the background div, as the following:

```css
.bg-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.top {
  height: 50vh;
  background: #76a3b1;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.title1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-container">
  <div class="top"><span class="title1">
            TEXT
        </span></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="main-page"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was under the impression that the padding which I wanted to add to the text would apply to the background too and leave white spaces around it. I was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @ZtxZ Glad I could help! don't forget to accept my answer ;p

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's much easier to use a linear gradient on the `body` element, with an abrupt change between color 1 and color 2.

If you want to center the page title, you can do it as in my snippet below. But also *without* these settings for centering (i.e. if it's *not* absolutely positioned), the background colors will remain *behind*  it.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #76a3b1 0%, #76a3b1 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd 100%) fixed, no-repeat;
}

.main-page {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-page">
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add z-index properties to the elements to control which falls in front of the other: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Note that this property only works on positioned elements, but you are positioning the text anyways so that should be fine in your case

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply here (but it's not very specific). Please copy the snippet demo from the question and demonstrate your solution. See [answer].

Comment: Already tried this, it doesn't work, thanks tho

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).